# Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am newbie to Spring and Hibernate. I am getting No session found for
current thread issue. I tried out looking other thread here but not 
able to resolve my issue.

Perhaps I am lacking some concept. Please do
help to understand what is the reason and how to resolve and please 
ignore my formatting, I am new on stackoverflow also. Thanks in 
advance.

**hibernate.config.xml**

```
<!-- Scan classpath for annotations (eg: @Service, @Repository etc) -->
<context:annotation-config/>

<bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
      p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.url}"
      p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>


<bean id="mySessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.shop.model"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>

        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
                      transaction-manager="txManager"/>
<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

**UserDaoImpl Class**

```
package com.shop.dao.impl;

@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements IUserDao {

    private static final Logger LOG =
            Logger.getLogger(UserDaoImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public boolean checkUser(String email, String password) {
        boolean userFound = false;
        String hql = "from UserInfo where email =? and password=?";
        LOG.info(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql));
        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter(0, email);
        query.setParameter(1, password);
        List userList = query.list();

        if ((userList != null) && (userList.size() 0)){
            userFound = true;
        }
        return userFound;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use openSession method of sessionFactory before creating query:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
```

Don't forget to close the session after your work is done.

Comment: thanks....that means, each time have to open and close the session, as per as i know, container handles this for us implicitly. In other way , '<bean id="userDao" class="com.shop.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl"> <property 
  name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" /> </bean>'  Configuring this in hibernate.config.xml  it works properly, and don't need to open and close the resources. it works fine with the same code.  I just need to do using annotation. Please correct me where i am wrong.